# LT1249 boost PFC controller CAout pin

Tags: boost, power-factor-correction

Looking at the reference design for the [LT1249 PFC controller](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/1249fbs.pdf) below:

[image]

What is the purpose of the CAout pin? Are there any equations on how to setup the resistor and capacitor network?

Comment: As is says on the datasheet this is the output of the current amplifier that senses and forces the line current to follow the reference signal that comes from the multiplier by commanding the pulse width modulator. When CAOUT is low, the modulator has zero duty cycle.

Comment: Does that mean its just a shutdown feature? also how would you calculate the network of capacitors and resistors (10kohm, 1nF and 100p) connected to the pin?

Comment: I understood that these values are predefined because CAOUT may need to swing 5V over one line cycle at high line condition, 11mV will be present at the inputs of the current amplifier if gain is rolled off to 450 at 120Hz (1nF in series with 10k at CAOUT).